# Non-friend operator+ with two parameters in Wandevoorde&Jossutis' book

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, friend

Learning **Expression templates**.

In Wandevoode and Jossutis's book *Templates, the complete guide*, section **18.2.3 The Operators**, they define an `operator+` with two arguments but not as a `friend` method.

```
template <typename T, typename R1, typename R2>
Array<T,A_Add<T,R1,R2> >
operator+ (Array<T,R1> const& a, Array<T,R2> const& b) {
    return Array<T,A_Add<T,R1,R2> >
           (A_Add<T,R1,R2>(a.rep(),b.rep()));
}
```

I am a beginner and hence insecure about what I know about C++.

Shouldn't this `operator+` be a `friend`?

I tried

```
class A{
public:
    explicit A(int x) : a(x){};

    A& operator+(const A& x, const A& y){
        A temp{x.a + y.a};
        return temp;
    };
private:
    int a;

};
```

I am getting a *binary 'operator+' has too many parameters*.

Comment: It doesn't have to be if it doesn't access any non-public members.

Comment: If this function access private or protected data then it should probably be a friend. Otherwise it will do fine on its own.

Comment: I see. I think I had got the idea that `A+B` would call `A.operator+(B)` when `operator+` is a member method or `operator+(A,B)` when it is a friend. So, it also makes sense `A.operator+(A,B)`.

Comment: @Karene: No, `A.operator+(A,B)` makes no sense. `A+B` can call `operator+(A,B)` if it's a non-member, whether or not it's a friend. Being a friend just gives it access to private members, which isn't needed here.

Comment: @MikeSeymour I keep getting a 'too many parameters' error. Using VisualC++ in Visual Studio, if that makes any difference.

Comment: The member function version of operator+ has only one argument.  The object it is called on is the left hand side.

Comment: @RetiredNinja Yes, that is what I had read and that is the reason for my question. Shouldn't the operator in the book be a friend? .... OOOooooh!!!! I just realized. Maybe in the book the operator+ definition is not inside a class definition. Is that it?

Comment: Yes, that's it!!! Thanks to all of you.

Comment: Yes, the function in the book is not a member function.  The reason you might make it a friend is if it needs access to non-public members or functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your "binary" `operator +` member function gives you the "too many parameters" error because it has three parameters: the `x` and `y` you specified, plus the implicit `this` parameter.  This means it actually takes three arguments, which of course is impossible.

You can make a member function taking one explicit parameter and the implicit `this`, but in the opinion of many people, these binary operators such as add and subtract are better implemented outside the class, in the same namespace as the class, as free functions taking two explicit parameters.  This works especially well if the data needed to fulfill the operation can be publicly accessed (otherwise you must use `friend`, which is OK if truly necessary).

Answer (score 0):

To summarize for the next reader.

There seem to be three forms of overloading binary arithmetic operators.

**First:** A member method taking one parameter by `const` reference. The `const` tothe return value is used (according to [this reference](http://courses.cms.caltech.edu/cs11/material/cpp/donnie/cpp-ops.html)) to avoid `(x+y)=z`.

```
class A{
  const A operator+(const A& other){
    // ... 
  };
};
```

**Second:**  A friend method, and therefore included in the definition of the class, taking two parameters.

```
class A{
  friend A& operator+(const A& operand1, const A& operand2){
    // ... 
  };
};
```

**Third:** A non-member method taking two parameters.

```
class A{
  // ...
};

A operator+(const A& operand1, const A& operand2){
   // ...
};
```